# Suggestions for guiding water leak into drain

Tags: water, basement, leak, waterproofing

We have a water leak in the unfinished portion of our basement. We are in the process of having the issue remedied but it will take several weeks. In the meantime we have having issues guiding the water towards the drain and not towards the finished part of the basement. We put down sandbags and sprayed water resistant foam around them but the water still flows around and underneath them instead into the direction of the drain. It’s not a huge issue but it does require us to place towels daily which is a nuisance. If there was an easy fix it would be very convenient for us. Thanks!

Comment: Is it seepage from underground through walls or floor? Or is it a leaky pipe? Pictures?

Comment: Can you go upstream to divert the water before it reaches the basement?

Comment: The floor needs to be clean and dry before any adhesive/sticky stuff will bind solidly/stop water flowing under it.  Any dirt/dust/wetness will leave gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've done what it makes sense to do: sandbags and a sealant. You might try a different sealant, such as butyl rubber under plastic sheeting. Anything that's really good at stopping absolutely all the water is likely to have downsides such as requiring more cleanup, being expensive, or requiring a dry surface to adhere.

At this point, I would add a dehumidifier if you don't already have one, and keep using rags as you have been.